# Android application with Android library project as external module

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

In my Android application project I want to use https://github.com/Bearded-Hen/Android-Bootstrap/tree/master/AndroidBootstrap as a dependency (I use Android Studio 0.8.8).

This is my settings.gradle

```
include ':gui', ':client', ':Android-Bootstrap'
project(':Android-Bootstrap').projectDir=new File('/abs/path/to/Android-Bootstrap/AndroidBootstrap')
```

And my gui/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.3'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }

...
skipped
...
}

dependencies {
    ...skipped...
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.1.0'
    ...skipped...
    compile project(':client')
    compile project(':AndroidBootstrap')
}
```

When I gradle sync I get::

```
Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'android-library' not found.
```

If I remove

```
project(':Android-Bootstrap').projectDir=new File('/abs/path/to/Android-Bootstrap/AndroidBootstrap')
```

I get

```
Error:(44, 0) Project with path ':AndroidBootstrap' could not be found in project ':gui'.
```

If I change https://github.com/Bearded-Hen/Android-Bootstrap/blob/master/AndroidBootstrap/build.gradle with

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

I get

```
Error:(1, 0) Plugin with id 'com.android.library' not found.
```

If I add to https://github.com/Bearded-Hen/Android-Bootstrap/blob/master/AndroidBootstrap/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.3'
    }
}
```

I get

```
Error:(44, 0) Project with path ':AndroidBootstrap' could not be found in project ':gui'.
```

How to fix it? I want this module be external, no import and copying into main project. Why fixing gradle plugin dependency leads to path not found issue?

Comment: try 'settings.gradle'  with  include ':AndroidBootstrap'

Answer (score 0):

Fix as follows in settings.gradle:

```
include ':gui', ':client', ':AndroidBootstrap'
project(':AndroidBootstrap').projectDir=new File('/abs/path/to/Android-Bootstrap/AndroidBootstrap')
```

Note that Android-Bootstrap is replaced with AndroidBootstrap (not dash)

And in root build.gradle (./build.gradle)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.13.3'
    }
}
```

It will override (set) buildscript dependencies in AndroidBootstrap.

There is not need to make changes in AndroidBootstrap itself.